# IHP - Best way to combine and sort data from two tables into a single view?

Tags: ihp

I have two tables:

```
Table: Posts
Columns: id, title, body, author_id, created_at

Table: Comments
Columns: id, post_id, body, author_id, created_at
```

I have the following action:

```
action MyAction:
 posts <- query @Post |> fetch
 comments <- query @Comment |> fetch
```

I want to fetch all the posts and comments together, combine and order them by created_at in a single view. What's the best way to do it in IHP inherently?

Comment: Voting to close. Lacks details and clarity.

Comment: I think the answer is somewhere around https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/relationships.html#has-many-relationships

Comment: @MichaelLitchard I've updated the question. Its a question for IHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: See Marc's answer: `collectionFetchRelated` is the correct function here

For a has many relationship such as this, the comments for a post can be queried using `fetchRelated #comments`. To do this for each post we can use `mapM` as follows.

```
postsWithComments <- query @Post 
           |> fetch
           >>= mapM (fetchRelated #comments)
```

To order by `created_at`, use the `orderByDesc` function for the `QueryBuilder`. We can apply this to the top level query directly, then modify the internal `#comments` query building using `modify`.

```
postsWithComments <- query @Post 
           |> orderByDesc #createdAt
           |> fetch
           >>= mapM (fetchRelated #comments . modify #comments (orderByDesc #createdAt))
```

See the [IHP "relationships" docs](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/relationships.html) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `collectionFetchRelated` for that:

```hs
posts <-
    query @Post
        |> fetch
        >>= pure . map (modify #comments (orderBy #createdAt))
        >>= collectionFetchRelated #comments
```

[You can find this code in the IHP documentation here.](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/relationships.html#order-with-multiple-records)

Comment: Is it possible to combine this with pagination? E.g. if I want to order by number of comments, but have the posts paginated.

Comment: Like this?

```haskell

(postsQuery, pagination) <- query @Post
        |> orderBy #commentsCount
        |> paginate

posts <- postsQuery
        |> fetch
        >>= pure . map (modify #comments (orderBy #createdAt))
        >>= collectionFetchRelated #comments
```

Comment: Aha, nice! I ended up with a handy helper `onRelated getter modifier = pure . map (modify getter modifier)` for this, so it looks like 
`fetch
        >>= onRelated #comments (orderBy #createdAt)
        >>= collectionFetchRelated #comments`

Comment: This looks really nice, we should add this to IHP as a standard helper IMO :)